# Changing Circle fillColor in google maps api

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, ionic2, ionic3

so I have created a button which is creating a Circle on a Google map.

```
this.Circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: this.map,
    center: this.map.getCenter(),
    radius: 100,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
});
```

I would like to set typz() so it would be changing color of the circle to black.

```
typz(){
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/polygon#Circle), you set the color using the `fillColor` option:

```
function changeColor(circle) {
  if (circle.get("fillColor") == "black") {
    circle.setOptions({fillColor:"red", strokeColor: "red"});
  } else {
    circle.setOptions({fillColor: "black", strokeColor: "black"});
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5r0thdL8/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function changeColor(circle) {
  if (circle.get("fillColor") == "black") {
    circle.setOptions({
      fillColor: "red",
      strokeColor: "red"
    });
  } else {
    circle.setOptions({
      fillColor: "black",
      strokeColor: "black"
    });
  }
}

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    center: map.getCenter(),
    radius: 100,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('tog'), 'click', function(evt) {
    changeColor(circle);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

#map_canvas {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="button" id="tog" value="toggle color" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```